# Generate methods dynamically giving the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Looking to find a solution(not sure if it exists!) to the following situation:
Starting point is a dictionary

```
dict = {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,kn:vn}
```

where `n` is ***not*** fixed.
Is there a way to write a generic class that will have `n` methods generated dynamically that can be called as in the following example:

```
    class example(dict):  
    example.k1()
    example.k2()
    .
    .
    .
    example.kn()
```

Each

```
example.ki()
```

where `1<=i<=n`, should return the corresponding `vi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to override the `__getattr__` function [described here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

To take your example:

```
class example(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda: self[name]
```

This allows you to do:

```
e = example()
e["foo"] = 1
print e.foo()
==> 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating so many method dynamically better override `__getattr__` method of your class and return a callable from there:

```
class Example(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, k):
        if k in self:
            return lambda: self[k]
        raise TypeError('Example object has not attribute {!r}'.format(k))
```

Note that for keys like `keys()`, `items()`, etc `__getattr__` won't be called as they are found in the class by `__getattribute__` itself. And better don't name any of your keys after them.

**Demo:**

```
>>> d = Example(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> d.a()
1
>>> d.b()
2
>>> d.foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    d.foo()
  File "/home/ashwini/py/so.py", line 7, in __getattr__
    raise TypeError('Example object has not attribute {!r}'.format(k))
TypeError: Example object has not attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: How would you list (in a programmatic way) all the methods that `d` has once it has been created?

Comment: @flamenco `[getattr(d, k) for k in d]`

Comment: Your answer is similar to David's who is a new user. I hope you don't mind if I accept his solution. He deserves some credit for jumping straight into answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a method to class dynamically can help u.

```
class example(object) :
            dict={'k1':'v1','k2':'v2','k3':'v3','kn':'vn'}
            def getvalue(self,key) :
                return self.dict[key]
if __name__=="__main__" :
e = example()
e.method1=e.getvalue     # this is adding a method to example class dynamically.
print e.method1('k1') 
e.method2=e.getvalue
print e.method2('k2')
e.method3=e.getvalue
print e.method3('k3')
e.methodn=e.getvalue
print e.methodn('kn')
```

this outputs 
v1
v2
v3
vn

Comment: Good solution but I want the names of the methods to be the names of the keys.

Comment: ok then i think adding a method to class dynamically can help u. i have just edited my answer check out..